# Poor performance after switching from EC2 Percona to RDS MySQL. What am I missing?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

**Current RDS Setup**: db.r3.2xlarge running in Multi-AZ, 8 VCPU, 61GB RAM, 1500GB EBS Volume with 5000PIOPS, Mysql5.6

Here are our current MySQL variable values: https://gist.github.com/jonhatalla/abfb0b8fb73690352629

**What we did before**: We are coming from an EC2 instance (of similar specs) running percona mysql 5.6 with ephemoral storage.

**What we expected**: Slightly slower read and write times, due to the round trips to EBS.

**What we experienced**:

We started using the RDS setup with full production traffic and initially we noticed that database queries were taking about 10ms longer than we experienced with EC2-MySQL. They were initially constant, however we started noticing spikes in response times of average queries which were longer than a second. This spike was not related to an increase of traffic or connections.  We were forced to return traffic to our EC2 database.

We weren't experiencing any application errors, all web requests were returning, just very slowly.

Note: We were serving traffic for around 2 hours on the RDS instance.  I tried to link times between cloudwatch metrics on the bottom with new relic graphs on top.

Here are our metrics from both new relic and cloudwatch:
[image: All Metrics]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Quite honestly the underlying hardware is the same. Is your rds instance in the same az as your ec2 instance? Can you post a gist of 'SHOW STATUS'? I run the same instance size in production as you and percona on a dev machine that is far beefier. It still is a close performance call sometimes. So it is likely just a config var issue.

Comment: also - can you post graphs for bin log / available mem metrics?

Comment: Show status gist: https://gist.github.com/jonhatalla/3d5a5b206d384cda6b75

Comment: binary disk usage: http://ofp-public.s3.amazonaws.com/devops/binarydiskusage.png

Comment: freeable memory: http://ofp-public.s3.amazonaws.com/devops/freeable-mem.png

Comment: what is the approx percentage workload split between read/write?

Comment: The workload is mostly writing, with some reading. Probably write 80% and read %20

Comment: Upon more investigation into RDS cloudwatch metrics for that time period, we were doing greater than 90% write and less than 10% read operations

Comment: upon review of what you've got there this looks like some anomalous behavior i had recently when i first restored a db from a snapshot - the binlog was pretty full and i had very high write rates for ~4-5h - then it just dropped off - nothing showing on query monitor either. Have you been able to replicate the issue since the instance has been idle?

Comment: We switched back to our old ec2 database - we stopped writing to the rds database. - We haven't tried to replicate the issue, as we were hoping the switchover would be clean and one way